# How does a question become a Hot Network Question?

Tags: discussion, meta, hot-network-questions

I see that one of my questions became a HNQ -- what did it?  Was it active here and THEN became "hot", or did I use some words that drew the HNQ attention, and then it got more views?

I just want to know, because if it's word choice, then we as writers should be masters of it, and thus be able to summon/dismiss HNQ at our whim.

I think HNQ is how I came here originally, lo these many days ago. ;)

Comment: There should be something in [Meta Stack Exchange's \[hot-questions\] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-questions), but I'm not up to digging through it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Hotness" is automatically computed based on some combination of votes, number of answers, and *velocity* -- a new question that quickly gets a bunch of answers and/or votes will score higher.  As far as I know, the formula doesn't do any actual content analysis, aside from blacklisting certain words in titles.  (The hot list shows up all over the network, so even if a question involving certain language is perfectly *reasonable* on a language site, health site, etc, SE isn't going to spread it all over the place.)

So, clickbait titles make a difference, especially once a question gets onto the list and then the feedback loop starts (title -> clicks -> higher score -> clicks -> higher score -> ...).  It's perfectly fine to write attention-getting titles *so long as they don't detract* -- the goal of a question title is still, first and foremost, to summarize the question.  This is something I expect our community to be good at doing.

I found a [really old post documenting the formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/162102), but I think it's been changed a few times since then.  Further, there have been [recent discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/162102) about what to do with this list because it sometimes attracts controversy.  (You can see some of [my opinions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316937/162102) on this subject there.)